# Записать в определенный тег XML свое значение (golang)

Tags: xml, golang

Есть xml файл(из прим):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<servers version="1">
<server>
    <serverName>Shanghai_VPN</serverName>
    <serverIP>127.0.0.1</serverIP>
</server>
<server>
    <serverName>Beijing_VPN</serverName>
    <serverIP>127.0.0.2</serverIP>
</server>
```

```
package main

import (
"encoding/xml"
"fmt"
"io/ioutil"
"os"
 )

 type Recurlyservers struct {
Svs []server `xml:"server"`
}

type server struct {
ServerIP string `xml:"serverIP"`
 }

func main() {
file, err := os.Open("go.xml") // For read access.
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    return
}
defer file.Close()
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    return
}
v := Recurlyservers{}

err = xml.Unmarshal(data, &v)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    return
}
for _, v := range v.Svs {
    fmt.Println(":::", v.ServerIP)
}

}
```

Как мне в данный тег записать что нибудь свое?

Comment: 1. т.е. вам нужно заменить <serverIP>127.0.0.1</serverIP> на <serverIP>что-то другое</serverIP> для какого-то одного serverName, а остальные записи не трогать? 2. Какой контекст задачи - например иногда проще и безопаснее (с т.з. сохранения структуры документа) работать просто со строками. Например найти по строкам нужный пункт и его поменть, а xml-парсерами вообще не пользоваться.

Comment: Ну да. К примеру: Есть  запись такого ip:<serverIP>127.0.0.1</serverIP> мне надо найти тег с данным содержимым и поменять его на что то другое, и вот я не как не могу найти информацию как мне, не выгружая всю структуру, найти и заменить данное значение. Если скинете пример, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Нет, мне интересно можно ли в xml файле не выгружая его весь в программу поменять значения полей??

Comment: Не переписывая весь файл получится только в частном случае - когда у вас старое и новое значение равны по длине. Иначе весь файл (или его хвост) придется переписыавть. Урощенный пример на строках можно посмотреть тут https://play.golang.org/p/eaLFSJg8y_ если у вас большой xml (гигабайты например) - можно сделать что-то аналогичное, но через поиск прямо в процессе чтения, без загрузки всего xml в память сразу. Такой подход будет быстрее любого xml-парсера и точно не будет портить остальную структуру документа.

Comment: Для доп. защиты можно еще найти конец куска через strings.Index(subXml, "</server>") и работать только с ним - чтобы не испортить соседний элемент если в текущем вдруг serverIP не окажется.

Comment: Дак я и не могу найти пример, как сделать что бы не загружая весь файл в память, обработать пару строк... Как работать с выгруженным полностью файлом я разобрался достаточно быстро

Comment: Как вариант - открыть файл и читать через bufio.Scanner построчно или потегно (свою функцию сканирования надо написать) и аналогично - искать нужный тег вручную. Еще можно через xml.Decoder/xml.Encoder - парсить файл по-токенно и так же по-токенно писать в вывод. А как нашелся нужный элемент - поменять его. Пример парсера можно посмотреть тут: http://blog.davidsingleton.org/parsing-huge-xml-files-with-go/ плюс - работать с xml на логическом уровне (теги, значения, атрибуты и т.п.). В память всё читается маленькими кусками. Минус - затраты процессора на полноценный разбор xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае вам придётся описывать в структурах полностью весть xml, иначе потеряете узлы в результирующем xml-ле:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Servers struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"servers"`
    Version int      `xml:"version,attr"`
    Items   []Server `xml:"server"`
}

type Server struct {
    ServerName string   `xml:"serverName"`
    ServerIP   string   `xml:"serverIP"`
}

func main() {
    data := `
<servers version="1">
    <server>
        <serverName>Shanghai_VPN</serverName>
        <serverIP>127.0.0.1</serverIP>
    </server>
    <server>
        <serverName>Beijing_VPN</serverName>
        <serverIP>127.0.0.2</serverIP>
    </server>
</servers>`

    servers := Servers{
        Items: []Server{},
    }

    _ = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &servers)

    for i := range servers.Items {
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", servers.Items[i]) // Output 1
    }

    for i := range servers.Items {
        servers.Items[i].ServerIP = fmt.Sprintf("test - %d", i)
    }

    resultXml, _ :=  xml.Marshal(servers)

    fmt.Print(string(resultXml)) // Output 2
}
```

Output 1:

```
main.Server{ServerName:"Shanghai_VPN", ServerIP:"127.0.0.1"}
main.Server{ServerName:"Beijing_VPN", ServerIP:"127.0.0.2"}
```

Output 2:

```
<servers version="1"><server><serverName>Shanghai_VPN</serverName><serverIP>test - 0</serverIP></server><server><serverName>Beijing_VPN</serverName><serverIP>test - 1</serverIP></server></servers>
```